# Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher in windows 10

Tags: maven, windows-10

I am using windows 10  and i have set the path as mention in the instruction

- Set M2_HOME (E:\softwares\apache-maven-3.3.9)
- Set M2 (%M2_HOME%\bin)
- Set system variable path (%M2_HOME%\bin)

When i run mvn --version i am getting error

```
    C:\Users\zafaque>echo %M2_HOME%
E:\softwares\apache-maven-3.3.9

C:\Users\zafaque>mvn --version
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue using the source zip archive files from the maven.apache  website. I solved using the Binary zip archive files.

Comment: Thanks @Patricia it work for me as well when i downloaded Binary zip archive files